# Parse formatted strings containing 3 delimiters to create multiple flat arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, preg-match-all, text-parsing

I have strings in following format:

```
$strings[1] = cat:others;id:4,9,13
$strings[2] = id:4,9,13;cat:electric-products
$strings[3] = id:4,9,13;cat:foods;
$strings[4] = cat:drinks,foods;
```

where `cat` means category and `id` is identity number of a product.

I want to split these strings and convert into arrays `$cats = array('others');` and `$ids = array('4','9','13');`

I know that it can be done by foreach and explode function through multiple steps. I think I am somewhere near, but the following code does not work.

Also, I wonder if it can be done by `preg_match` or `preg_split` in fewer steps. Or any other simpler method.

```
foreach ($strings as $key=>$string) {
   $temps = explode(';', $string);
   foreach($temps as $temp) {
      $tempnest = explode(':', $temp);
      $array[$tempnest[0]] .= explode(',', $tempnest[1]);
   }
}
```

My desired result should be:

```
$cats = ['others', 'electric-products', 'foods', 'drinks';
```

and

```
$ids = ['4','9','13'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be doing a string compare for the first item after explode for `cat` and `id` to set the values to the right array.

```
$strings = ["cat:others;id:4,9,13", "id:4,9,13;cat:electric-products", "id:4,9,13;cat:foods", "cat:drinks,foods"];

foreach ($strings as $key=>$string) {
    $temps = explode(';', $string);
    $cats = [];
    $ids = [];
    foreach ($temps as $temp) {
        $tempnest = explode(':', $temp);

        if ($tempnest[0] === "cat") {
            $cats = explode(',', $tempnest[1]);
        }
        if ($tempnest[0] === "id") {
            $ids = explode(',', $tempnest[1]);
        }
    }
    print_r($cats);
    print_r($ids);
}
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/erjiF)

Output for the first item would for example look like

```
Array
(
    [0] => others
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 13
)
```

---

If you want to aggregate all the values in 2 arrays, you can array_merge the results, and at the end get the unique values using array_unique.

```
$strings = ["cat:others;id:4,9,13", "id:4,9,13;cat:electric-products", "id:4,9,13;cat:foods", "cat:drinks,foods"];
$cats = [];
$ids = [];
foreach ($strings as $key=>$string) {
    $temps = explode(';', $string);

    foreach ($temps as $temp) {
        $tempnest = explode(':', $temp);

        if ($tempnest[0] === "cat") {
            $cats = array_merge(explode(',', $tempnest[1]), $cats);
        }
        if ($tempnest[0] === "id") {
            $ids = array_merge(explode(',', $tempnest[1]), $ids);
        }
    }

}
print_r(array_unique($cats));
print_r(array_unique($ids));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => drinks
    [1] => foods
    [3] => electric-products
    [4] => others
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 13
)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/sSDj4)

Answer (score 1):

I don't generally recommend using variable variables, but you are looking for a sleek snippet which uses regex to avoid multiple `explode()` calls.

Here is a script that will use no `explode()` calls and no nested `foreach()` loops.

You can see how the `\G` ("continue" metacharacter) allows continuous matches relative the "bucket" label (`id` or `cat`) by calling `var_export($matches);`.

If this were my own code, I'd probably not create separate variables, but a single array containing `id` and `cat` --- this would alleviate the need for variable variables.

By using the encountered value as the key for the element to be added to the bucket, you are assured to have no duplicate values in any bucket -- just call `array_values()` if you want to re-index the bucket elements.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/huZClk)) ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vofjcn/1))

```
$count = preg_match_all(
    '/(?:^|;)(id|cat):|\G(?!^),?([^,;]+)/',
    implode(';', $strings),
    $matches,
    PREG_UNMATCHED_AS_NULL
);

$cat = [];
$id = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    if ($matches[1][$i] !== null) {
        $arrayName = $matches[1][$i];
    } else {
        ${$arrayName}[$matches[2][$i]] = $matches[2][$i];
    }
}
var_export(array_values($id));
echo "\n---\n";
var_export(array_values($cat));
```

---

All that said, I probably wouldn't rely on regex because it isn't very readable to the novice regex developer.  The required logic is much simpler and easier to maintain with nested loops and explosions.  Here is my adjustment of your code.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6vRYe))

```
$result = ['id' => [], 'cat' => []];
foreach ($strings as $string) {
   foreach (explode(';', $string) as $segment) {
      [$key, $values] = explode(':', $segment, 2);
      array_push($result[$key], ...explode(',', $values));
   }
}

var_export(array_unique($result['id']));
echo "\n---\n";
var_export(array_unique($result['cat']));
```

P.s. your posted coding attempt was using a combined operator `.=` (assignment & concatenation) instead of the more appropriate combined operator `+=` (assignment & array union).

Comment: which one is more efficient ? this regex method or explode-foreach loop method ?

Comment: Unless you are dealing with tens of thousands of strings in your input array, I doubt there is any noticeable difference in efficiency.  If you _need_ to know which one runs faster, I recommend that you write your own benchmarking script and see which one performs better in your actual environment with your actual data.  That aside, I will urge you not to waste time on premature optimization.  You should choose the "cleaner" approach that is easier to maintain and read.  This especially important if you work on a team of developers where regex isn't everyone's strong suit. Use the 2nd snippet.

Comment: I have tried this code in my script. My Php version is 5.6.4. I am getting error PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '='   , it points this line: [$key, $values] =

Comment: You are using a deprecated version of php.  You should upgrade asap.  In the meantime, use `list($key, $values)`... then you are going to tell me that you can't use the splat operator either `...`.  https://3v4l.org/7B1GK